# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException - Droping message with size more than max limit and pushing into another kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

> **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException**: There are some messages at [Partition=Offset]: {binlog-0=170421} whose size is larger than the fetch size 1048576 and hence cannot be returned.

Hi, I'm getting the above exception and my apache beam data pipeline fails. I want the kafka reader to ignore message with size more than default size & maybe push it into another topic for logging purposes.

```
Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
kafkaProps.setProperty("errors.tolerance", "all");
kafkaProps.setProperty("errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name", "binlogfail");
kafkaProps.setProperty("errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor", "1");
```

Tried using the above but still facing record too large exception.

[Kafka Connect sink tasks ignore tolerance limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420059/kafka-connect-sink-tasks-ignore-tolerance-limits)

This link says that the above properties can be used only during conversion or serialization.

Is there some way to solve the problem that I'm facing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace? If yes, please post it here. I guess it's not a KafkaIO issue and likely related to your broker configuration as @cricket_007 mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the kafka reader to ignore message with size more than default size

With Beam, I'm not sure you can capture that error and skip it. You would have to go to the raw Kafka Consumer/Producer instances to handle that try-catch logic

> & maybe push it into another topic for logging purposes.

That isn't possible without changing *the broker settings* to first allow larger messages, and *then* changing your client properties.

`errors.*` properties are for Kafka **Connect** APIs, not Consumer/Producer (such as Beam)

Related - [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)

Comment: We are only consuming, producer is not in our control. Is there any way in which in the consumer side through which I can ignore such large messages which rarely comes. This is for a precautionary measure to ignore such events

Comment: The producer would be getting the same error. It's the broker that rejects large messages, by default. If the broker has been updated, you need to update the consumer settings, as per the linked post. And again, no, you need access to the poll / process loop within Beam

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check it.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to use the checkmark next to the post to accept ;)